# Combine elements of an array into a sub array if they are the same

Tags: javascript, sorting

Trying to find an algorithm that will do the following:

```
let input = [ 'kooty', 'dlnnoo', 'emor', 'dlnnoo', 'kooty', 'aiprs' ]

function combine(input){
  // you should return 

  [ ['kooty', 'kooty'], ['dlnnoo','dlnnoo'], ['emor'], ['aiprs'] ]
}
```

I got the answer by using Lodash but i was wondering if there was a way without

```
function combine(input){

  let sortedCity = [];
  let finalArr = [];


  for(let city in input){
    sortedCity.push(input[city].toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''));
  }
  let a = lodash.groupBy(sortedCity)

  return Object.values(a)

}

combine(input)
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at all yourself yet? Please post the code you've tried

Comment: Sorry...first time asking a question.. ill know for next time, i edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = [ 'kooty', 'dlnnoo', 'emor', 'dlnnoo', 'kooty', 'aiprs' ]

function combine (input) {
    let sorted = input.map(cur => cur.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join(''))
    let cache = {} // cache value to index of result array
    return sorted.reduce((sum, cur) => {
        let index = cache[cur]
        if (index !== undefined) {
            sum[index].push(cur)
        } else {
            sum.push([cur])
            cache[cur] = sum.length - 1
        }
        return sum
    }, [])
}
combine(input)
```